# Analogs for perl pack/unpack (B*) functions for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to port code from perl that [packs byte string](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html). In perl it looks like the following:

```
pack 'B*', '0100001000111110010100101101000010010001'
```

I don't see `B*` format analog in [python struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html). Perhaps there are ready solutions not to invent a bicycle?

Honestly, [description is not clear for me, so i even can't imagine how it works](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) to implement it by myself:

> Likewise, the b and B formats pack a string that's that many bits
>   long. Each such format generates 1 bit of the result. These are
>   typically followed by a repeat count like B8 or B64 .
>
> Each result bit
>   is based on the least-significant bit of the corresponding input
>   character, i.e., on ord($char)%2. In particular, characters "0" and
>   "1" generate bits 0 and 1, as do characters "\000" and "\001" .
>
> Starting from the beginning of the input string, each 8-tuple of
>   characters is converted to 1 character of output.
>
> With format b , the
>   first character of the 8-tuple determines the least-significant bit of
>   a character; with format B , it determines the most-significant bit of
>   a character.
>
> If the length of the input string is not evenly divisible
>   by 8, the remainder is packed as if the input string were padded by
>   null characters at the end. Similarly during unpacking, "extra" bits
>   are ignored.
>
> If the input string is longer than needed, remaining
>   characters are ignored.
>
> A * for the repeat count uses all characters
>   of the input field. On unpacking, bits are converted to a string of 0
>   s and 1 s.

So, string is divided in chunks for 8 symbols. If last chunk is less 8 symbols, it is padded with null characters in the end to be 8 symbols. Then, each chunk becomes a byte.

But i can't understand, what are resulting bits? What is meant under B8 and B64 here?

Answer (score 2):

The `int`-object has a `to_bytes`-method:

```
binary = '0100001000111110010100101101000010010001'
number = int(binary, 2)
print(number.to_bytes((number.bit_length()+7)//8, 'big'))
# b'B>R\xd0\x91'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the exact perl semantics, but here's my guess at them:

```
def pack_bit_string(bs):
    ret = b''
    while bs:
        chunk, bs = bs[:8], bs[8:]
        # convert to an integer so we can pack it
        i = int(chunk, 2)
        # Handle trailing chunks that are not 8 bits
        # Note this as an augmented assignment, perhaps also read as
        # i = i << (8 - len(chunk))
        i <<= 8 - len(chunk)
        ret += struct.pack('B', i)
    return ret
```

Comments are inline.  If you know things like "the input is less than 64 bits" you can avoid the loop and use `Q` for struct.pack